# How do I disable only the Clicked button for a mapped over component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am mapping over the `request` variable and rendering it on the page, it has an array of object with a `question`, `correct_answer` and `incorrect_answer` properties, and I also set a state named `disable` that is toggled between  true and false when the `correct_answer` button is clicked to make the correct answer button get disabled or unclickable for each question, but clicking the correct answer button for ONE question disables all correct answer buttons for the OTHER questions

I basically want to disable the correct answer button on click or making it clickable once

```js
const [request, setRequest] = React.useState([])
const [disable, setDisable] = React.useState(false);


function scoreFunction (event){
 setDisable(true)
setScore(prevScore => prevScore + 1)
}
 
        
React.useEffect (() => {
        fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setRequest(data.results.map(({ question, correct_answer, incorrect_answers }) => ({question, correct_answer, incorrect_answers}))))
    }, [])

    
    // console.log(request)

const questionElements = request.map(req => {
    return (
        <Question 
        question = {req.question}
        correct_answer ={req.correct_answer}
        incorrect_answers = {req.incorrect_answers}
        scoreFunction = {scoreFunction}
        disabled = {disable}
         />
    )
})




// The Question Component

export default function Question (props){

const incorrectAnswers = props.incorrect_answers.map(ans => {
    return (
        <button className ="button">{ans}</button>
    )
})
    
    return(
        <div  className = "question-div">
        <h1 className = "question">{props.question}</h1>
        <div className = "answerBlock">
        <button 
        disabled = {props.disabled}
        className ="button correct"
        onClick = {props.scoreFunction}>{props.correct_answer} </button>
        {incorrectAnswers}
        </div>
        <hr />
        </div>
        
    )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete, where is `disabled` actually stored? Please edit with the full code.

Comment: @AdamThomas I have edited the code, You can check it now please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially the issue is because your disabled `useState` is in the wrong place. It needs to be inside the `Question` component so you have 1 disabled flag per question rather than 1 global one.

```js
export default function Question (props) {

    const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false)

    const incorrectAnswers = props.incorrect_answers.map(ans => {
        return (
            <button className ="button">{ans}</button>
        )
    })
    
    return(
        <div  className = "question-div">
        <h1 className = "question">{props.question}</h1>
        <div className = "answerBlock">
        <button 
        disabled = {disabled}
        className ="button correct"
        onClick = {() => {
            setDisabled(true)
            props.scoreFunction()
        }>{props.correct_answer} </button>
        {incorrectAnswers}
        </div>
        <hr />
        </div>
        
    )
}
```